# Flip card with random display text from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, boolean

I am trying to make a card flip with clicks. One click, It flip to the back and display some random text from array. Click again, It flip to the front. But I don't want to change the random text when click from back to the front.

I was thinking use boolean loop in click function. When it is true(back card) then display the text. When it is false(front card) then display the same text or empty. Now, it is changing the text with every click. Please help?

```js
        var cards = [
          {animal:"Dog", animal_type:"A"},
          {animal:"Pig", animal_type:"B"},
          {animal:"Hippopo", animal_type:"B"},
          {animal:"Cat", animal_type:"A"}       
        ];
        
        
     
        var card = document.querySelector('.card');
        card.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
        card.classList.toggle('is-flipped');
                

            var display_text = true;
            if(display_text) {
                
                var random_num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);  
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = cards[random_num].animal + " " + cards[random_num].animal_type;
                
                return false;
            } else {
                
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
                
                return true;
            }
                

            
        });
```

```css
        body { font-family: sans-serif; }

        .scene {
          width: 308px;
          height: 446px;
          border: 1px solid #CCC;
          margin: 40px 0;
          perspective: 600px;
        }

        .card {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          transition: transform 1s;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
          cursor: pointer;
          position: relative;
        }

        .card.is-flipped {
          transform: rotateY(180deg);
        }

        .card__face {
          position: absolute;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          /*line-height: 260px;*/
          color: white;
          text-align: center;
          font-weight: bold;
          font-size: 40px;
          -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
        }

        .card__face--front {
          /*background: red;*/
        }

        .card__face--back {
          background: blue;
          transform: rotateY(180deg);
        }
```

```html
    <div class="scene scene--card">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card__face card__face--front">
          <img src="./css/images/pokemon_card.png" width="304" height="442" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="card__face card__face--back">
            <p id="demo">Back</p>
            
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some changes in the JavaScript.

```js
var cards = [
    { animal: "Dog", animal_type: "A" },
    { animal: "Pig", animal_type: "B" },
    { animal: "Hippopo", animal_type: "B" },
    { animal: "Cat", animal_type: "A" },
];

const
    $card = document.querySelector('.card'),
    $demo = document.querySelector('#demo');
let display_text = true;

$card.addEventListener('click', function () {
    $card.classList.toggle('is-flipped');

    if (display_text) {
        var random_num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
        $demo.innerHTML = cards[random_num].animal + " " + cards[random_num].animal_type;
    }

    display_text = !display_text;
});
```

```css
*, ::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    color: #333;
    font-family: "roboto","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.5;
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

article, aside, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, nav, section {
    display: block;
}

.scene {
    width: 308px;
    height: 446px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    margin: 40px 0;
    perspective: 600px;
}

.card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: transform 1s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}

.card.is-flipped {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card__face {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /*line-height: 260px;*/
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 40px;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card__face--front {
    /*background: red;*/
}

.card__face--back {
    background: blue;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="scene scene--card">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card__face card__face--front">
            <img src="./css/images/pokemon_card.png" width="304" height="442" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="card__face card__face--back">
            <p id="demo">Back</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```